# cache mysql query result?

Tags: php, mysql, caching

I use a several mysql queries on a page to fetch data from multiple tables using mysqli prepare statements.

Lets say i have like 20 queries from database tables on a page. Since there are so many queries, I would like to improve the performance by storing the results in cache for some minutes? Is it good idea? If yes, how I can store the results using cache for the , for example, following query?

```
$city = "Amersfoort";

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT District FROM City WHERE Name=?")) {
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $city);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($district);
    $stmt->fetch();
    printf("%s is in district %s\n", $city, $district);
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't mysql query cache (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html) fit in your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

If the SQL statements are cheap in processing, you probably don't need to cache them. If they require hefty calculations or run on really large datasets, you might need a cache. Remember that the cache needs to be faster than the SQL query.

There are several ways to cache in PHP:

- File cache, serialzing the data and storing it into a file named like the hash of the query. Remember that getting cache lifetime, concurrent accesses and so is hard  -so consider using a library that does it, i.e. with PEAR's [Cache](http://pear.php.net/package/Cache) or [Cache_Lite](http://pear.php.net/package/Cache_Lite)
- [memcached](http://php.net/memcached)
- shared memory as cache, i.e. by using APC functions like [apc_add](http://php.net/apc_add)

You also might want to cache the complete page or parts of the page instead of single queries.